# Can I use the word ''precedent'' in this example?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence with precedent.

''He rarely picked up the phone, so he created a bad precedent for himself.''

Comment: I don't see why that makes it *bad*. I'm also not sure if *precedent* is the right word in this case. Typically, it's used in a legal sense, where certain rulings can be used as a basis (or precedent) for future rulings. Or it's used as a justification for doing the same thing again or for somebody else to do it. Something unique ***sets*** *a precedent*. In this example, it's more like he established a pattern, giving other people the *expectation* that he would not answer the phone. (But the reason for it being *bad* is still not clear.)

Comment: What I meant to say is, that the person who doesn't pick up the phone makes a precedent, that he usually doesn't pick up the phone. Isn't this a bad thing.

Comment: Not eating your vegetables and getting away with it sets a (perhaps bad) precedent that there are no consequences for not eating your vegetables. Not answering your phone may (in terms of how the word is normally used) set a precedent that you don't have to answer your phone. Or, if nothing bad happens if you don't answer the phone, sets a precedent that not answering the phone results in nothing bad. But typically (although not always) a precedent requires something to only happen once. And there is a correlation between that thing and something else.

Comment: ''He rarely picked up the phone, as he had a bad precedent for this.''

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of 'precedent'. It is usually a single event that sets a precedent, sets the pattern for future events. Since he 'rarely' does X, the pattern has already been repeated and recognized as what will happen again. Are you looking for writing advice about what would be a good word instead of 'precedent'? Or for you want a better context in order to use 'precedent' correctly?

Answer (score 4):

While the sentence is grammatically correct, It does not mean what I think you want it to mean.

To *set a precedent* means to take an action in a situation such that when that same situation occurs again, the same action would be expected (or even required). This either occurs the first time a situation is encountered or the first time some different action is taken in response to a situation.

For example, in the US some companies give new mothers (women who have just given birth) more time off than new fathers (men whose female spouses have just given birth) to attend to their new baby. Now that same-sex marriage is legal in the US, a company may for the first time be asked to state how much time off a woman is given when her spouse gives birth. Whatever they decide the first time that happens will *set a precedent* for future similar cases.

If, in the future, they do something different, then they will *break the (old) precedent* and *set a new precedent*.

If someone "rarely" picks up a phone, that is not setting a precedent one way or the other, so I think your sentence is wrong based on what it means.

Perhaps you mean something like this:

> Since he rarely answered the phone, he knew that taking her call would show he cared more about her than he would like to admit.

To *set a bad precedent* means to take an action in a situation that is different than what you want to do in future similar situations (or what you want people to think you will do). If a manager at a company is supervising his daughter and gives her time off from work to get her hair done, *he is setting* (or *it sets*) *a bad precedent* if he does not want to give everyone time off to get their hair done, because other employees expect everyone to be treated equally.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather odd thing to say, but it is grammatical and its meaning is reasonably clear.

It's odd because what is not clear is in whose mind the precedent has been established: is it saying that the person who is calling will now expect him to pick up the phone? Or that people around him will? Or that he himself is somehow now committed to picking it up? But if the context had been established, it could make sense.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to asnwer. It is saying that the person who is calling will NOT expect him to pick up the phone, because from the numerous times he has been called, he rarely picked up. Thats why it is a bad precedent, it happenned myriad times.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood your intention. This indicates that it is not very clear! (Though some context might have helped).